# Symbolic Computation in Eigen C++

Tags: c++, matrix, sparse-matrix, eigen, exponential

Using the Eigen library in C++ I need to calculate the matrix exponential. So I do something like this

```
double t = 1000;
MatrixXd L(N,N);
MatrixXd K_t(N,N);

K_t = (-t*L).exp()
```

Where L is some already specified sparse, self-adjoint matrix. However, I need to do this for many values of t. So I have to repeat this calculation over and over again which can be a drain. So I was wondering if there would be a way to to calculate the matrix K_t for arbitrary t "symbolically" and then specify what t's I need so that I only need to calculate the matrix exponential once.

Is this even possible? If so how could I do it? I'm kind of stuck in this regard as I don't even know what this would be called in C++. If this isn't possible is there a way to do this better besides the way I suggested. Thanks for any help.

Comment: It doesn't make sense. Exponential of a general square matrix is defined by its Taylor expansion. You don't want to symbolically represent the whole series. And, Eigen is a numeric library anyway, its algorithms are designed to compute to numbers.

Comment: I was just wondering if it would be possible to have a place holder of sorts for t then specify it. And I believe Eigen uses the scale squaring method for its matrix exponential.